# Can not install eclim

Tags: linux, eclipse, vim, eclim

Has anyone used eclim? I wanted to try it out and I use vim as my primary editor so I want to run it as a headless instance. Anyway I installed it via the Unattended (automated) install
`$ java \
  -Dvim.files=$HOME/.vim \
  -Declipse.home=/opt/eclipse \
  -jar eclim_2.4.0.jar install`

I had already downloaded eclipse luna and I have jdk 7 installed (but I don't know if it is part of the environment variables) and I ended up with:

```
2014-08-30 10:37:40,569 INFO  [ANT] [eclim:unattended] Finished analyzing your eclipse installation.
2014-08-30 10:37:40,572 ERROR [ANT] 
jar:file:/home/jim/Downloads/eclim_2.4.0.jar!/installer.xml:119: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:116)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
        at org.formic.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:232)
        at org.formic.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:81)
        at org.formic.ant.Main.main(Main.java:63)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.run(Boot.java:306)
        at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.main(Boot.java:159)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.formic.Installer.getString(Installer.java:201)
        at org.eclim.installer.step.FeatureProvider.getFeatures(FeatureProvider.java:99)
        at org.eclim.installer.ant.UnattendedInstallTask.execute(UnattendedInstallTask.java:73)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        ... 16 more
2014-08-30 10:37:40,582 DEBUG [ANT] 
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 19 seconds
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

So I have no idea what happened. But I can not find `eclimd` anywhere in my system

Comment: If **eclimd** is installed correctly, you should find it in ECLIPSE-FOLDER. Anyways, I have always found installation problems with command line. May b try with GUI-mode, you might get a better info for whats going on.

Answer (score 1):

`/opt` is owned by root per default. My guess is that it indeed is in your setup and since eclim needs to write to `/opt/eclipse` during installation it results in an error. Try changing ownership of `/opt/eclipse` using the -R option or run the installation as root. Note though that using `$HOME` will then probably not lead to the desired result.

Comment: That command was copy paste from the eclim site. When I run it I replaced `/opt/eclipse` with `$HOME/path/to/my/actual/eclipse/` Was that wrong?

Comment: That contradicts with what you wrote in your question. In the command that you provided there you are using `/opt/eclipse` in the installation. So the path `$HOME/path/to/my/actual/eclipse/` is the one that you are actually using?

Comment: Yes.I downloaded that eclipse funa and pasted it in a subdirectory in my home directory and I referenced that. I did not understand that `/opt/eclipse` is actually where it should be pasted.So I was wrong at that?

Comment: No, you can have your eclipse installed wherever you want as long as you provide the respective path at the installation of eclim - as you apparently did correctly.

Comment: Hm I think I actually had a similar exception when I installed eclim - maybe even the same. Using the graphical installer worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I followed the instructions to build from the source code and that worked for me.

I checked out the master branch from the Git repository and used ant to build and install eclim. At the time of this writing that resulted in version `2.4.0.11-ge560abe` getting installed without errors. Running `eclimd` and then `:PingEclim` and `:EclimValidate` from vim reported that everything is fine.

Note that eclimd dumped an exception on startup:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to aquire PluginConverter service during generation for: /home/pappmar/dev/eclipse/plugins/org.eclim.installer_2.4.0.11-ge560abe.jar`

I don't know if that's a problem or not. It seems to be running all the same.